# REST pattern for for query parameters that might be LIKE searches

Tags: rest

Hi I'm building a RESTful app and can't find the recommended way to pattern optional fuzzy or LIKE queries.  For example a strict query might be,

```
/place?city=New+York&state=NY
```

Corresponds to SQL "... WHERE city="New York" AND state="NY"

But what if I wanted to search for the city field for any row with "York" in city name?

"... WHERE city LIKE "%{parameter}%" AND state="{parameter2}"

I'm thinking about just adding some kind of url-valid character to the request like this:

```
/place?city=*York*&state=NY
```

Is there an established or recommended pattern I should use?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's fine to use query string for searching, but it's a little bit weird to use macro character like "*" or "?" in query string(unless you decide to build a really powerful search  engine like Google). More importantly, search is usually considered in fuzzy mode by default, so it's redundant to append/prepend the keyword with "*". If you do need exact search, you could surround the exact(or strict) keyword with double quotes. Namely, instead of using `/place?city=*York*&state=NY`, I recommend `/place?city=York&state="NY"`.

In fact, Google uses quotes to search for an exact word or set of words, and I also found [this site](http://webhelp.esri.com/geoportal_extension/9.3.1/index.htm#rest_details.htm) takes this pattern.